# AngularJS1: how to create a constant map, fetched from an API at application load

Tags: angularjs, api

I have an angularJS 1 application and in that I have created a factory which calls up an API to fetch some constants an creates a map using those.

```
app.factory('myFactory', '$http', function($http) {
  this.myMap = {};
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url',
    headers: {'Content-Type': '*/*'}
  }).then(function (response) {
    for (var i in response.data) {
      this.myMap[response.data[i].key] = response.data[i].value;
    }
  }).finally(function() {
    return {
      getMyValue: function(key) {
        return this.myMap[key];
      }
    };
  });
});
```

Now, I want this factory to be created and instantiated only once when the application loads and then, I want to call the factory's getMyValue() method from my controller to get the value from the Map.

Right now, using the above code fails and it gives me this error:

> https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/docs/error/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20string

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your factory is not returning anything. In a service, you attach your functions and members to `this`, but in a factory, you must return something.

I see you have a return statement in the `.finally()` block, but that does nothing for your factory, since that code is not in scope until long after the factory is done being instantiated.

Personally, I would forego the `.finally()` block, as it doesn't really give you any added benefit:

```
app.factory('myFactory', '$http', function($http) {
  var myMap = {};
  var apiPromise;

  // this will only run once as soon as the factory is instantiated
  // and will store the resolution of the call for future use
  apiPromise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'url',
        headers: {'Content-Type': '*/*'}
     }).then(function (response) {
       for (var i in response.data) {
         myMap[response.data[i].key] = response.data[i].value;
       }
     });


  return {
    getMyValue: function(key) {
      // apiPromise prevents this function from returning until $http call is complete
      // but will not cause the $http call to run again
      return apiPromise.then(function() {
        return myMap[key];
      });
    }
  };

});
```

To use this you must treat the return value as a promise and not a value:

```
MyFactory.getMyValue(key).then(function(myMap) {
  console.log(myMap);
});
```